# AWS - How to trigger a Lambda based off of a Cloudtrail Event Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I have a cloudtrail trail set up. It goes into CloudWatch and I have and event rule which I want to trigger a lambda when a specified event name comes up. I have tried different rules, watching both Cloudtrail and Cloudwatch, but cannot get it to call my Lambda.

```
{
"source": [
  "aws.cloudtrail"
],
"detail-type": [
  "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
],
"detail": {
  "eventSource": [
    "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com". 
  ],
  "eventName": [
    "CreateFunction20150331"
  ]
 }
}
```

The above does not trigger my lambda when Event Name "CreateFunction20150331" Is shown in the logs.

Comment: `CreateFunction20150331` does not seem to me to be a correct eventName. Where did you get it from?

Comment: @Marcin In my Cloudtrail events. That is the name I see under Event Name for creating a lambda function.

Comment: The event name needs to be an Action on the event source, where the event source is the AWS service the action is performed on. 

In your case you want to find events where a lambda function is created. The service is `lambda.amazonaws.com` and the action `CreateFunction20150331`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html

Answer (score 0):

your source is wrong. it should be like this:

```
{
"detail": {
  "eventSource": [
    "lambda.amazonaws.com". 
  ],
  "eventName": [
    "CreateFunction20150331"
  ]
 }
}
```

the create function is correct for what is in cloudtrail. If it helps, I stumbled onto this tool that helps with writing the correct event:

https://www.intelligentdiscovery.io/tools/cloudtrailevents

Comment: You could explain in detail how/why this solution works to solve OP's question/problem and what was wrong in OP's source & why it was wrong.  I am a reviewer.  StackOverflow requested review because you are a new contributor.  Your answer is appreciated & helpful.  This comment is intended to help you make a good answer into an excellent one.